# Global "box-sizing: border-box"

Tags: css, pseudo-element

This is a question that has been asked many times but my question is different, so please do not mark it as duplicate.

```
html { box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }
```

I understand what is happening in line 1. But I dont understand what is line 2. In line 2, "before" and "after" are pseudo elements. They need a "content" property. But I see all this missing here and it seems like these pseudo elements are being used for a different purpose.

Can someone please explain line 2.

Comment: Every element, `:before` of every element, `:after` of every element have `box-sizing: inherit` property - which means that each and all of them  inherit `box-sizing` from parent. If you won't specifically set box-sizing for some element - everything will have `box-sizing: border-box`

Comment: This is a duplicate of at least one other question, but if you didn't find it, it's probably because it had a terrible title, so I've improved the title. The fact that box-sizing is set to inherit in a separate rule in your question shouldn't matter, but if it bothers you I'm happy to reopen your question and answer it anyway.

Comment: @BoltClock, yes it is a duplicate. Thanks for pointing out and the other question helped me understand.